# Hadoop: `hdfs getconf -confKey [key]` what key arguments are available?

Tags: hadoop

When working on an unfamiliar cluster, I find it useful to dig around and inspect some basic configuration parameters (e.g. `hdfs getconf -confKey fs.blocksize`, `hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFs`).

**What other `key` arguments are available?** I'm looking for the most comprehensive document of `key` arguments available to inspect via `hdfs getconf -confKey [key]`.

I understand that some set of keys will be specific to your cluster (e.g. whether you can use Yarn and have `yarn.resourcemanager.address` available).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the property names can be used as `key`. For the list of property names you can refer the `*-default.xml` files.

- [core-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml)
- [hdfs-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)
- [yarn-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)
- [mapred-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

The `name` column in these files can be used as key with `hdfs getconf -confKey`. The returned value will be the one set in corresponding `*-site.xml` file if set else the default value.